# How to patch JS function that doesn't belong to a class

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-16

I'm a complete JS n00b and I'm really struggling to figure this out. I'm trying to change the default colors used in graphs. There's a 'getColors' functions in web/views/graph/colors.js that simply returns an array of colors that are used for this and it seems best to me to just override this function with my own array of colors but I can't for the life of me figure out how to patch it because this function does not belong to a class.

The original code (that I want to patch) looks like this (notice that none of this is inside a class):

```
/** @odoo-module **/
const COLORS_BRIGHT = [
    "#1f77b4",
    // rest removed for brevity
];

const COLORS_DARK = [
    "#00ffff",
    // rest removed for brevity
];

// this is the function I want to replace with my own
export function getColors(colorScheme) {
    return colorScheme === "dark" ? COLORS_DARK : COLORS_BRIGHT;
}

// a few more functions that I don't care about
```

I've created my own colors.js like this

```
/** @odoo-module **/    
import { patch } from '@web/core/utils/patch';
import { getColors } from '@web/views/graph/colors';

const MY_COLORS_BRIGHT = [
    "#1f77b4",
    // rest removed for brevity
];

const MY_COLORS_DARK = [
    "#00ffff",
    // rest removed for brevity
];

patch(getColors, 'my_module.colors', {
    getColors(colorScheme) {
        return colorScheme === "dark" ? MY_COLORS_DARK : MY_COLORS_BRIGHT; 
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work - it adds a new getColors function inside the old getColors function instead of replacing it. Normally I think I would patch the Class with getColors function and that would work I think but there is no class to patch in this case. How can I go about replacing this function without it having a parent to patch?

Comment: If you created your own `colors.js` file then just don't import the `getColors` function and use your own. I don't get what you mean by "this is not a class" because it is just a simple function export within a module. you can't override that function (that's not the idea of modules) except you modify the source itself. the problem are the constants `MY_COLORS_BRIGHT` - these are returned in the function, you would need to change their values.

Comment: the `getColors` function (or actually `getColor` function in original `colors.js` file) is used in dozens of places across Odoo. I can't (or rather don't want to) inherit/patch/otherwise modify all locations that call this function to instead call my own. I need to instead patch the original function to call a different one. I've solved this problem - see my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my own problem. The key here is importing the entire colors.js file with `import * as colors` and then patching `colors` with the new function. I'm not sure why, but when doing it this way I was unable to patch the `getColors` function directly (the original one would still be called). But patching `getColor` (which is what all other modules actually call) and using my own `getMyColors` function it works.

```
/** @odoo-module **/
import { patch } from '@web/core/utils/patch';
import * as colors from '@web/views/graph/colors';

const MY_COLORS_BRIGHT = [
    "#1f77b4",
    // rest removed for brevity
];

const MY_COLORS_DARK = [
    "#00ffff",
    // rest removed for brevity
];

function getMyColors(colorScheme) {
    return colorScheme === "dark" ? MY_COLORS_DARK : MY_COLORS_BRIGHT;
}

patch(colors, 'my_module.colors', { 
    getColor(index, colorScheme) {       
        const colors = getMyColors(colorScheme); 
        return colors[index % colors.length]; 
    } 
});
```